# Событие для onclick

Tags: html

Ребят, 
у меня на странице есть 4 фрэйма с разным содержимым, мне нужно, чтобы по кнопке "обновить" содержимое фрэйма менялось (получает изображение с сервера), сопсна, я поставила кнопку

```
<input type='button' value ='обновить' onclick='window.location.reload()'/>
```

Но, как вы понимаете, она ни к чему не привязана, поэтому обновляет всю страницу. Меня такая ситуация не устраивает и вот уже 2 часа я пытаюсь это исправить, но пока тщетно.

P.S. Какое событие на onclick еще есть? А то я роюсь и не нахожу по своему запросу.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('id_твоего_фрейма').contentWindow.location.reload();
```